# Mapping DTO with final members in MapStruct

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, mapstruct

is there a way to map a DTO using MatStruct which have a few final data members as well and cannot have a default constructor , like :

```
public class TestDto {

    private final String testName;
    private int id;
    private String testCase;

    public TestDto(String testName) {
        this.testName = testName;
    }

    public String getTestName() {
        return testName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTestCase() {
        return testCase;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTestCase(String testCase) {
        this.testCase = testCase;
    }
}
```

please suggest how could this DTO be mapped using MapStruct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [@ObjectFactory](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories) that would construct an instance of your DTO.

For example:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @ObjectFactory
    default TestDto create() {
        return new TestDto("My Test Name");
    }

    //the rest of the mappings
}
```

You can also enhance the `@ObjectFactory` to accept the source parameter, that you can use to construct the `TestDto`. You can even use a `@Context` as an Object Factory.

NB: You don't have to put the `@ObjectFactory` method in the same Mapper, or even a MapStruct `@Mapper`. You can put it in any class (or make it static) and then `@Mapper(uses = MyFactory.class)`